# How to do an SQL LIKE in a select statement in a webpage source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have this SQL SELECT statement that I use to populate a lookup grid when the user clicks on the "Lookup" button. It currently works as follows:

```
"SELECT Trans_Serial_No, Empl_Id, WC_Id, Item_Number, Part_Number, Shift FROM SFD10000 WHERE (Empl_Id IS NOT NULL)"
```

But when I add: "AND (WC_Id LIKE 'GS3%')" as follows, it does not work.

```
"SELECT Trans_Serial_No, Empl_Id, WC_Id, Item_Number, Part_Number, Shift FROM SFD10000 WHERE (Empl_Id IS NOT NULL) AND (WC_Id LIKE 'GS3%')"
```

This is not in the `webpage.aspx.cs` code, but in the `webpage.aspx` source code.
If I put this command in an SQL query it works.

Comment: How about you add this `(WC_Id LIKE '%GS3%')` instead of this `(WC_Id LIKE 'GS3%')`

Comment: Makes no difference. Tried it both ways. Thanks

Comment: maybe...try enclosing them in first bracket... `((Empl_Id IS NOT NULL) AND (WC_Id LIKE 'GS3%'))`

Comment: Can you post some sample data for column `WC_Id` which has that matching value?

Comment: @Rakitić, shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Can you show an example of what the data in `WC_ID` looks like..? perhaps you can do `((Empl_Id IS NOT NULL) AND (WC_Id LIKE '%GS3%'))`

Comment: The data in WC_Id is either numbers such as "10", "40", "70"...etc or "GS3 A", "GS3 B", "GS3 C"

Comment: Please define "does not work" (no results, or error?) and also post calling code. Is this in a datasource, ADO, what else is going on?